# Getting Unexpected Java class loaded under Java version 11 (maximum supported version is 8): java.lang.AssertionError while querying SAP HANA database

Tags: jdbc, hana

I am trying to make a JDBC call to a SAP HANA database. My Java code version is Java 11. I am using ngdbc 2.11.14 HANA jdbc driver. I am getting below error.

```
Unexpected Java class loaded under Java version 11 (maximum supported version is 8): java.lang.AssertionError
java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected Java class loaded under Java version 11 (maximum supported version is 8)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.DriverSapDB._checkJavaVersion(DriverSapDB.java:2179)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.DriverSapDB.checkJavaVersionMaximum8(DriverSapDB.java:2154)
```

Also I can see in decompiler, below code in Driver.java file, which checks for maximum Java version 8. Does this mean SAP HANA JDBC driver does not support Java 11?

```
public class Driver extends DriverSapDB {
  static {
    checkJavaVersionMaximum8();
  }
```

Comment: The exception clearly says it isn't supported on versions higher than Java 8. It is unclear why you're asking confirmation for what the exception message already tells you. Possibly you need to check if there is another JDBC driver version or variant available for higher Java versions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel As a matter of fact the question makes sense as exactly this version of the driver does support Java 11 and above. The issue is likely caused by an incorrect handling of the multi-release jar.

Answer (score 2):

The SAP HANA JDBC driver is a [multi-release JAR](https://www.baeldung.com/java-multi-release-jar). From my basic understanding, this means that it carries separate class files for Java <= 8 and for Java > 8.

**Short answer to your question: Yes, the SAP HANA JDBC driver does support Java 11 (and above)!**

It seems your code (or framework) fetches the incorrect class files for Java 8 internally. I've had an issue in the past which resulted in the same error message that you see. For me, this has happened in the context of using OSGi and due to a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-6396) with multi-release JARs in Apache Felix.

You can read the details about my issue (..which may or may not be different from yours) in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/cytoscape-app-dev/c/Asv4ifiYY84).

Comment: Thanks Mathias Kemeter for the response. To add few points, my standalone java program to connect to SAP HANA using ngdbc latest ja rworks fine with java11. Issue comes when  I integrate with our framework. I just did a quick check to check the java version of the class where the jdbc connectivity happens, where I invoke DriverManager.getConnection(), it shows  major version: 55.

Comment: In this case, you need to check which part of your framework introduces the issue. I'd start with the bug I linked above. Could you be affected by this? (i.e. you're using Karaf < 4.3.x or OSGi < 7). For me the issue appeared when trying to package ngdbc as part of my app jar. My current "workaround" is to not do this with OSGi 6.